# Unable to retrieve Key Vault Secret from Docker App Service in .NET Core

Tags: azure, docker, .net-core, azure-keyvault

I'm running a Web API that use NET Core 3.1 from Azure App service in a docker container, and struggling to obtain a secret key from Key Vault Service. 
My code looks fine, y get no errors but the response is always empty. This is my Startup initializacion:

```
public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {   
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        this.bIsDevelopemnt = env.IsDevelopment();           

        Configuration = builder.Build();

        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));

        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
            $"https://{Configuration.GetSection("KeyVaultName").Value}.vault.azure.net/",
            keyVaultClient,
            new DefaultKeyVaultSecretManager());           
    }
```

And i'm using this controller to test the results, which returns null in all three cases:

```
[HttpGet("/secrets")]
    public IActionResult getSecrets()
    {
        try
        {

            var value = configuration["tokenKey"];
            var value2 = configuration["OhmioAPI:tokenKey"];
            var value3 = configuration["OhmioAPI--tokenKey"];

            return Ok(new { orign = "pirulo", key1 = value, key2 = value2, key3 = value3 });
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            return NotFound(e.Message);
        }            
    }
```

**What I have try/done**:
* Create the Key Vault Store and secrets
* Create an Identity ID for my App
* Add permission to get/list secrets from the key Store

Any Ideas?

Comment: Assume you are running in a Linux container? Have you given the managed identity get permissions explicitly in the key vault?

Comment: Yes Simon I am running a my app in a Linux container and I have given get permissions for the vault. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use Key Vault Reference.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Major Steps:

- Enable MSI on Azure WebApp
- Allow the WebApp to access the KeyVault via Access Policies in KeyVault
- Add an application say, test with the value:
  @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/ec96f02080254f109c51a1f14cdb1931)
  [Change the secretUri as per the secret's URI which you are trying to access]
- That's it. The WebApp will automatically get the secret from the KeyVault, which you can now access as if they were environment variable.
- You could echo the application setting (TEST in our case) to check if the value has been set

Comment: Are app settings available as an option for a web app running inside a docker container on app service, if so this is definitely the easiest option, then you simply give the app service the relevant permissions in the key vault then access them as Configuration values

Comment: Yes, they are available for Webapp for Containers as well.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav, will try this.

Comment: If is using a docker container then the Identity options is not available.